# Simulation of a time series using the unconditional moments

Tags: time-series, simulation, autoregressive

$y_{t}$ follows a covariance stationary AR(1) process

$ y_t = \phi y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t \hspace{1cm} \varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2) $

I want to simulate a time series $y_{1:T}$. Can I use the unconditional moments to simulate the time series, namely draw from

$y_t \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi^2}\right) \hspace{1cm}  t=1, \ldots, T $

to obtain $y_{1:T}$ ?

Comment: No.You can't do that because there's an autocorrelation structure of the AR(1) that will not be captured if you use that approach.